# Change Field's DisplayName in a List in view

Tags: 2010, list, list-view, list-definition

I have view with following fields

```
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="DocIcon" />
      <FieldRef Name="Title"  />
      <FieldRef Name="Modified" />
    </ViewFields>
```

I want to change name of a column, so I write

```
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="DocIcon" />
      <FieldRef Name="Title"  />
      <FieldRef Name="Modified" DisplayName="Badaboom" />
    </ViewFields>
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to change DisplayName in list definition? I know how to do it programmicaly, but xml seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the column name, you can simply select the field name from the List Settings page and change its title /column name to the desired name.

**Note:** the internal name of the column will still remain the same.

Comment: It is not possible becuase I have a list of this lists so i should specified it in shema. And problem is that it's a standard "modified" column.

Comment: And what it is hosted in Sharepoint Online ? How can you do it through schema definition ?